# Is there any other way to format my %echo output in OMAKE (Instead of using cygwin printf.exe but using any localized syntax of OMAKE it self)

Tags: clearcase, omake

The below I have pasted two approaches, but the second approach does not gives good structured output like the approach 1 does.

Please suggest me how to get the same good font with `OMAKE` internal syntaxes if any:

- approach 1:

  ```
  @:$(CC_WORKING_VIEW)/tools/Cygwin/bin/print '%-26s -%s\n' "$(target)" "$($(target)_DESCRIPTION)"
  ```

**Or:**

- approach 2:

  ```
  # %echo "$(target)"                  "$($(target)_DESCRIPTION)"
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo` alone would not support padding, as `print` or `printf` does.

As long as `Cygwin/bin` is in your $PATH (or `%PATH%` on Windows), you should be able to use directly `printf`:

```
printf '%-26s -%s\n' "$(target)" "$($(target)_DESCRIPTION)"
```

You can echo your `%PATH%` in your `omake` makefile, as shown in [this technote](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/PM39973).

```yaml
PATH=$(CWD)\buildtools;$(PATH)
# %setenv PATH=$(PATH)

all:
 echo %PATH%
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir